# Check if value of one column is in another table's column and return another column's value if it is

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables with a similar column called "Re", but the "Re" column in Table 1 is a list as shown below.

I want to search if Table2.Re is in Table1.Re and if so return Table1.FiN.

Table 1

```
 FiN       Re
  A     ,1,2,3,4
  B     ,6,7,8,9
  C     ,3,5,6,7
  D     ,7,10,11,24
```

Table 2

```
Re   
3
5
6
9
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: I appreciate the link. I did not create the tables, I just have to query the data from them.

Comment: To elaborate on @stickybit suggestion of not using comma delimited lists, the method he provided below is one of two ways. The other involves a split function. Both aren't fun and while one performs better than the other, it takes more work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with `LIKE`.

```
SELECT t1.[FiN]
       FROM [Table 2] t2
            INNER JOIN [Table 1] t1
                       ON t1.[Re] LIKE concat('%,', t2.[Re], ',%');
```

But seriously, you just should not use comma delimited lists.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I can see what you mean about not using comma delimited lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just like we use `INSTR(..)` for checking in an actual string if the substring exists same in this case `CHARINDEX(..)` will do the same if it matches then the value would be greater than 0. So, you get the desired output.

```
 SELECT  t2.RE FROM TABLE2 t2
 JOIN TABLE1 t1
 ON
 CHARINDEX(t1.re, t2.re)>0;
```

or 
Maks use of `like` as

```
     SELECT  t2.RE FROM TABLE2 t2
      JOIN TABLE1 t1
      ON
      t1.re LIKE "%,"+ t2.re + "%,";
```

Comment: what is `strpos`? Looks like a PHP function, which the question isn't tagged for. I've never seen it in SQL Server. And `TRIM` is only available in 2017, where as `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` are available in 2012 and earlier versions.

Comment: corrected i was trying to find equivalent of `instr` i think `charindex` is the one

Comment: there was actually no need of trim as well

Comment: When I run it, I get the error: Invalid column name ',%'

Comment: That's a double quote issue

Comment: yeah typo left edited can check now

Comment: There's still this error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',%' to data type int.